# can't get height and width of svg image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have this:

```
<img id="logo" src="../images/svg/logo.svg" type="image/svg"></img>
```

I cannot for the life of me qet the height or width of it either with jQuery of javascript, I've tried

```
$('#logo').height()
document.getElementById('logo').height;
$('#logo').css('height');
```

In Chrome or Firefox inspector it plainly states the width and height of the svg image, how come I can't get it in javascript???

SOLVED
Stupid me, I had to wait for the image to load..

```
$('#logo').load(function(){
console.log( $(this).height() );
});
```

Comment: Dude if you've solved it, add your answer to your own question and accept your own answer. Will help people in future :)